# error using php to print out special charcters from a database

Tags: php, mysql, html

Alright, what I'm trying to do is print out a few lines of text onto a page from a database, and the problem I'm running into is when it sees something like a `'` in the text, it puts out a `?`. So what I'm wondering is there a way around this? I know with HTML you can use special characters, but I'm working with dynamic data here. I did try doing this, but it's just not working:

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

$queryCurUser = "SELECT * FROM wn_current;";

$queryResult2 = mysql_query($queryCurUser, $conn) or
                   die ("queryResult Failed: ". mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult2))
{

 $body = $row['body'];
    echo $row['heading'];
    echo"<br/>";
    if($body == "'"){
    echo"hot dog";
    }
    echo"<br/>";
    echo $row['pdflink'];

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$body=str_replace['"', "&quot;", $body];  // double quotes
```

seemed to work

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the character set used in the database to one with more characters - UTF-8, for instance.

Comment: I set it to utf8_general_ci it was under Collation in phpmyadin and it's still doing it. Did I set the wrong thing?

Comment: collation and charset are related, but not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the browser what encoding the data is.

Most likely this tag will solve your woes:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

If that doesn't work, try this one:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the character set that your database table uses; you may want to change it to use UTF-8.  Also consider using htmlentities() on your echoed output with the correct charset to convert any characters that have HTML character entity equivalents, e.g.

```
echo htmlentities($body, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store international characters (á, ê, etc..), not only do you need to choose the correct character encoding for your database (e.g. UTF-8), but you also need to tell the browser to use the correct character set, by way of

a meta tag:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

or a php header:
`header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`

Also, it may be necessary to specify the charset that the MySQL extension should use with [mysql_set_charset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php).